# Why don't we need to count the two pre-assigned people in this committee forming probability question?

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

The following question comes from MITx 6.431x.

---

> Out of five men and five women, we form a committee consisting of four
> different people. Assume that 1) each committee of size four is
> equally likely, 2) Alice and Bob are among the ten people being
> considered.
>
> Calculate the probability that both Alice and Bob are members of the
> committee.

I know the correct solution to this problem; what I do not understand is why isn't $(1/5)^2*\binom{8}{2}/\binom{10}{4}$ the correct way to calculate.

- $(1/5)^2$ because both Alice and Bob have a 1 out of 5 chances of being picked
- $\binom{8}{2}$ because after Alice and Bob have been picked, there are two spots left to fill out of 4 men and 4 women
- $\binom{10}{4}$ because that's the total amount of combinations possible

Could anyone help please? In particular, $(1/5)^2$ is not necessary - why?

Comment: I don't see where your $(1/5)^2$ comes from in the first place. I don't see anything that the committee has to have at least one woman and at least one man. Quite the opposite, actually, it says that *all* committees of size four are equally likely, that therefore includes committees of four men or four women. Unless there's something you didn't quote, the individual numbers of men and women here is just a red herring. Alice and bob are just two of ten people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\left(\frac15\right)^2$ is (incorrectly) the probability of both Alice and Bob being picked. That's it. It is, by itself, a complete (but still incorrect) answer to the problem. It would have been correct if we had wanted the committee to consist specifically of exactly one man and exactly one woman, rather than four people without gender restrictions.

The correct answer to this problem is
$$
\frac{\text{Number of committees with Alice and Bob}}{\text{Number of possible committees in total}}
$$
There are no probabilities in neither numerator nor denominator here. There is no room for $\frac15$ anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I understand that the correct solution is $\binom{8}{2}/\binom{10}{4}$, but I don't get how have Alice and Bob been taken into consideration by $\binom{8}{2}$...because that only seems to have taken care of the '2 people out of 4men+4women' part, would you mind elaborating a little more please?

Comment: @DanielMak The number of committees that contain Alice and Bob is found by first picking Alice and Bob (which can be done in 1 way), then picking the remaining two members from the remaining 8 people (which can be done in $\binom82$ ways).

Comment: Ah I got it, because this is about combination so $AB$ and $BA$ count as 1, so I can read it as $\binom{8}{2}*1$ where the 1 denotes the 1 way Alice and Bob are picked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have already accounted for choosing Alice and Bob in the second bullet. Why are you considering it twice?